# Two quick Ruby questions

Tags: ruby

I've defined this class that contains an array and I have problems implementing the `each` method for it.

---

```
class Number
include Enumerable
def initialize
  @array = []
end

# for some reason this doesn't work on the the @array members
# when calling each
# and I also have to return an Enumerable if no block is given
def each &block
  @array.each do |number| 
  block.call (number) 
 end
end
```

---

And also the second part is: How can I rewrite the following code, so that I have no `return` statements.

---

```
  def determine number # @sing is a member of another class I have
    return true if (@sign == :negative && number < 0)
    return true if (@sign == :positive && number > 0)
    return true if (@sign == :non_negative && number >= 0)
    true if (@sign == :non_positive && number <= 0)
  end
```

Comment: It's generally better to ask a *single* specific question.

Comment: Your second question has answers in [the previous question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515855/union-of-filters-in-ruby). Also, "how do I rewrite" questions should be asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: Something like `@range` would be a better name than `@sign`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to handle this with `block_given?`:

```
class Number
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @array = []
  end

  def each
    if (block_given?)
      @array.each do |number|
        yield(number)
      end
    else
      @array.each
    end
  end
end
```

As for the other thing, remember you can just condense your logic:

```
def test?
  (...) || (...) || (...)
end
```

Since you're returning `true`, just return the evaluation of each bit of logic. Remember that there's an implicit `return` in Ruby, so it's not necessary to request one unless you're doing something more complicated than computing a binary condition.

Considering how you're basically testing against a variety of cases, best rewrite it as a `case` statement:

```
def determine(number)
  case (@sign)
  when :negative
    number < 0
  when :positive
    number > 0
  when :non_negative
    number >= 0
  when :non_positive
    number <= 0
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: Or you could just use `def each(&block); @array.each(&block); end`

Comment: @engineersmnky If you want to just chain it through, yeah, that should work. This exposes a bit more of the inner workings so you can add on to it.

Comment: your answer is more clear as to how it works for sure. I mean if I really wanted to confuse the OP I would have posted an answer that extended `Forwardable` and used `def_delegators`.